# Android: how to add my app to default phone app list just like truecaller

Tags: java, android, telephony

I want to add my app to phone app list programmatically like truecaller did So user can select my app from this list.

[image]

Please help me. Thanks

**EDIT:**
Here is the article to add SMS app to default SMS app list. 
https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html

I need same kind of article for Phone App.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />                
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="tel" />
     </intent-filter>
```

**Note:** permission tag is need to allow phone call.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Comment: Sorry but it's not working. I'm testing it in Android 8.1

Comment: try to replace action `<action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />`

Comment: Still no luck. Is there anything else I should do or shouldn't? FYI I'm testing it in completely blank app.

Answer (score 0):

You can add:

```
  <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL"/>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
      <data android:scheme="tel"/>
  </intent-filter>
  <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL"/>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
  </intent-filter>
```